# Font icons on android 2.3.4

Tags: css, font-face

I want to use icon fonts from http://weloveiconfonts.com.
But, it's not working on android 2.3.4. It shows only the blank squares.
The strange thing is that some icons are displayed.

[image: Website's screen shot]

Is there a way that it will display the icons?